# how to make jQuery's .empty perform more efficiently

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hosting a page which has a kendo grid. The kendo grid has 500 rows. The grid has around 20 columns(clicking on them opens dialog boxes and blah blah). In essence, the DOM structure of the whole grid is huge.

Now I have a case, where the user changes an id and I need to redraw the whole grid with a new set of data.

The problem is with the .empty function - to clear the grid I use,

```
var container  = $("#kendoGrid");
container.empty();
```

This function takes a lot of time - almost around 3 seconds in chrome(Version 35.0). Is there some other way, I can avoid using empty? There was this Google group discussion at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jquery-dev/8eL0jCezhiU but it seems very old and there isnt any proper solution provided for it.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the innerHTML to ""?

Comment: or removing the container element altogether?

Comment: I believe innerHTML wouldn't suffice since it doesn't take care of garbage collection?

Comment: Before all of this, I'd have to ask, why you presenting the user with 500 rows?  That seems very excessive.

Comment: Do you really need to destroy and rebuild the entire table?

Comment: @Erik: Perfect! That was first reacyion - introduce pagination for God's sake. But some users wanted to be able to edit 100s of rows at one shot, hence, the huge grid :(

Comment: @crisbeto: is there really difference from performance perspective between .remove() and .empty()? I can very delete the container node and add it again but I doubt that would be helpful!

Comment: you don't need to worry about garbage collection, especially if you use delegated events.

Comment: There are any number of things that can be added to `jQuery.cache` without the user knowing, so the garbage collection aspect is very important. Setting the `innerHTML` to `""` should not be done without great care.

Comment: If it's the same grid but with new data, I don't understand why you'd want to tear down the grid instead of just updating the data. Unless this is another one of those cases where everything is managed by some 3rd party library, and it doesn't offer any facility to simply do an update.

Comment: well if there are cell-bound events that need tearing down, that might be why it's taking 3 seconds to do it"the right way". with un-bound html and top-element events, the inner table html shouldn't matter to jQuery.

Comment: ...there are solutions like asynchronous batching that will make the UI responsive while updating. It doesn't really fix the issue though. It just masks it a bit.

Comment: @dandavis: Stuff gets put into `jQuery.cache` for various reasons. Even doing `.show()` or `.hide()` on an element will do it. And it sounds like this is some sort of plugin, so it could be adding `.data()` for elements.

Comment: don't use jQuery for projects where performance matters is the take-away i guess... Or live within the limits using work-arounds like pagination or batching, or live with the slowness and appreciate how easy and awesome using huge libraries made your project to get 80% satisfactory.

Comment: @cookiemonster given the alternative response time, why doesnt he profile it then?